# Getting errors when trying to use the online material library add on

Tags: python, add-on

[image]

The title pretty much says it all

Comment: Welcome Rcprobot :) This one: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Material/Online_Material_Library ?

Comment: I try to install this on 2.75 and nothing shows up in the materials UI. No error message as above but nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The online material library was originally written to work with older versions of blender, for more recent blender versions the addon has been broken since the python api relating to nodes and groups changed. As the author has had more important things to do it has been neglected for a while, but I understand he plans to get back to it soon.

I have submitted an update that is waiting to get approved and merged into the official contrib repository, until then you could use my patched version. While I did make a change to get group exporting working, there seems to have been another change that broke group exports so only materials without groups are working at present. I don't think any of the available library materials have groups so it would only affect materials you export.

You can download [this one file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sambler/myblendercontrib/master/online_mat_lib/__init__.py) that was changed and use it to replace the `addons_contrib/online_mat_lib/__init__.py` that you have now. Another option is to download my entire [contrib repo](https://github.com/sambler/myblendercontrib/archive/master.zip) (about 20MB) which also has other addons included and copy the `online_mat_lib` folder (or all of it) into the `addons_contrib` folder.

Comment: thanks for the answer I do hope someone gets it back up and running soon I guess I can just keep appending materials individually in the meantime

Comment: Thanks very much for sharing but the script file seems to missing from the link and from the repo.

Comment: It was removed from the [official contrib repo a week ago](https://developer.blender.org/rBACe4a8d40525f5228d3afbc546a3689a83d4968e79) and I missed replacing it. It is back now. I had thought of starting a replacement for the online material library, maybe now I should.